# which VR SDK is best for unity application?

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality

I need some help about VR camera which VR SDK is best and support all Device like(Mixed Reality, Oculus Rift and HTC Vive).any idea quick..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to build an VR-Application for Desktop-VR (like Oculus, WMR, Vive), you can just roll with SteamVR which supports them all.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Google VR SDK.
[Download link](https://github.com/googlevr/gvr-unity-sdk/releases)

Comment: google vr sdk is in its development phase. So they are releasing the versions . Use stable versions from their github page.

Comment: Google VR SDK is common or not.it will support multiple devices or not.